Send an email to a person who filled out an approval
I'm trying to send an email to a person who filled out an approval google form after a decision has been made. The email must be sent after we change a value in the corresponding sheet to 'Goedgekeurd' (= approved) or 'Afgekeurd' (= rejected) in a certain column.
The script needs to get the email address from the same row as the changed value.
After running the script, I do not receive an email.
See the script below:
function onEdit(e) {
try {
var editedColumn = e.range.getColumn();
var editedSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
// Checks if the edit is made in the right sheet and right column (column J)
if (editedSheet.getName() == "SheetName" && editedColumn == 10) {
  var editedRow = e.range.getRow();
  var editedValue = e.value; 
  var recipientEmail = editedSheet.getRange(editedRow, 2).getValue();
  
  // Checks if the email address in the same row as the changed value isn't empty
  if (!recipientEmail) {
    Logger.log("E-mailadres is leeg op rij " + editedRow);
    return;
  }

  // Makes an email depending on the changed value
  var subject, body;
  if (editedValue == "Goedgekeurd") {
    subject = "Goedkeuringsbericht";
    body = "Uw aanvraag is goedgekeurd.";
  } else if (editedValue == "Afgekeurd") {
    subject = "Afkeuringsbericht";
    body = "Uw aanvraag is afgewezen.";
  } else {
    return; 
  }
  
  // Sends the email to the email address found in the sheet
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, subject, body);
}

} catch (error) {
Logger.log("Fout: " + error.message);
}}


Perhaps it is because simple triggers cannot perform operations that require permission

To send an email when a spreadsheet is edited by the user on the keyboard, instead of using a simple trigger, onEdit, you must use an installable trigger.
First, you should change the function name to avoid it being triggered twice, i.e., from function onEdit(e) { to function editHandler(e) {. For details to create the installable trigger, please checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable.
Also, you should learn about the execution logs to find when a trigger failed and if there is an error message. For details, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting.
Related

onedit why cannot send email?

